# Can't install clean-webpack-plugin for nodejs

Tags: node.js, npm, aurelia, npm-install

npm install --save-dev clean-webpack-plugin
produces the following error:

```
npm ERR! path /home/dovetail/dealware/node_modules/latest/node_modules/npm/node_modules/dezalgo/node_modules/asap
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/home/dovetail/dealware/node_modules/latest/node_modules/npm/node_modules/dezalgo/node_modules/asap' -> '/home/dovetail/dealware/node_modules/latest/node_modules/npm/node_modules/dezalgo/node_modules/.asap.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

Have tried:
Wiping the node_modules directory and npm install
Checking file permissions.

Node version: 8.11.4
NPM version: 5.6.0

Answer (score 1):

Your issue looks like the ones mentioned in this thread: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17444

You are probably hitting an issue of npm itself or between npm and another process on your system.

Issues in npm itself are mostly fixed by upgrading npm. (Sometimes by downgrading...)

Scanning the issue thread indicates your issue could very well be your ide, a virus scanner, or another (npm?) process that is running in the background. Quitting these processes could fix your problem.

Some people mention deleting package-lock.json fixes the problem, but keep in mind this deletes important information about the versions of your installed packages so make a backup first.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.
Downgraded from npm 6 to npm 5.2.0